# Which of these url structures is better practice

Tags: seo, url-design

I just had a quick question about URL structures. Out of these structures which is more commonly used, and should be used more for best practice. Or if you had any other ways that are even better, that would be appreciated.

Create all `add` type pages with a prefix of `add-` and then the rest

```
http://example.com/add-account
```

or create a `folder` for all `adding` functionality

```
http://example.com/add/account
```

Comment: If you're building an API, I'll suggestion you to add `http://example.com/account/add` to the possible ways ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a SEO point of view, I would think that add-account would be nice. But like Joël said, if you are focusing on a sane URL structure, /account/add would suffice, and I do not think it would be worse for SEO.

It's not that important for an account page anyway. If it were a clothes shop I would recommend example.com/products/women/dresses/red-dress-with-flowers as the URL. Not women-dresses-red-dress-with-flowers :)